# Python. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase'

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord, discord.py

Hello I am connecting my discord.py bot to firebase realtime database but I am getting this error

```
2021-02-28T10:21:29.394213+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-02-28T10:21:29.394282+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "filename.py", line 7, in <module>
2021-02-28T10:21:29.394582+00:00 app[worker.1]:     from firebase import firebase
2021-02-28T10:21:29.394726+00:00 app[worker.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase'
```

And I have already installed

```
pip install firebase
And
pip install python-firebase
```

Discord.py

```
from firebase import firebase

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("data I can't show this, None")
data = {
  'Total Members':'200',
  'Bots':'10',
  'Humans':'190',

}


result = firebase.post('/organic-pe-form-default-rtdb/discord', data)
print(result)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that you installed it in your machine, from the logs I can see you're hosting the bot on heroku, did you put the module in the requirements.txt file?

Comment: PH let em put it

Comment: I am using firebase==4.3.0 in requirements.text but it is returning the same error

Comment: Put the requirements.txt file in the question.

Comment: Also there's no such version of that module, the newest one is 3.0.1.

Comment: OK I will try 3.0.1

Comment: I suggest reading https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-started-with-firebase-using-python/

Comment: The 3.0.1 error is over but I am getting this error

Comment: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
2021-02-28T11:19:57.682031+00:00 app[worker.1]:     import python_jwt as jwt
2021-02-28T11:19:57.682084+00:00 app[worker.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_jwt'

Answer (score 0):

Requirements.text

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py 
dnspython==1.16.0 
PyNaCl==1.3.0 
async-timeout==3.0.1
discord.py==1.5.1 
firebase-admin==4.3.0 
firebase==4.3.0
```

Comment: Youre supposed to edit your question, not create an answer